# Can an interface define functions which discriminate based on the implementors class?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm trying to define an interface that has a function that only accepts the class type which implements it. Here is what I have so far:

```
public interface ICombinableAction : IAction {
    public bool CombineActions(ICombinableAction toCombine);
}

public class MoveAllObjects : ICombinableAction {
    public bool CombineActions(ICombinableAction toCombine) {
        if (!(toCombine is MoveAllObjects)) {
            // This isn't possible, inform the caller
            return false;
        }
        ... // Combining logic
        return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as the function can't check at compiletime the type of the object passed in I have to handle the case where an incompatible class is used, and then handle that in the caller.

Ideally this would be possible by defining the interface such that only instances of the same class are possible, something along the lines of:

```
public interface ICombinableAction : IAction {
    public void CombineActions(Implementor toCombine);
}

public class MoveAllObjects : ICombinableAction {
    public void CombineActions(MoveAllObjects toCombine) {
        ... // Combining logic
    }
}
```

I suspect that isn't possible due to the anwer in [C# Interfaces: Is it possible to refer to the type that implements the interface within the interface itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3330294/3922839). I suspect that this question [Why C# doesn't allow inheritance of return type when implementing an Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319663/3922839) is also skirting around the same issue that I am. Neither of these questions helped me to reach a solution for my particular problem though.

What would be a good solution in this case?

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your problem correctly - you can achieve something like this with generics:

```
public interface ICombinableAction<T> where T : ICombinableAction<T>
{
    public void CombineActions(T toCombine);
}

public class MoveAllObjects : ICombinableAction<MoveAllObjects>
{
    public void CombineActions(MoveAllObjects toCombine)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: A potential problem with this method is if you want a `List<ICombinableAction<T>>` where T is different for one or more elements you want to put in the list.

Comment: @JacobHuckins yes, valid point, but this can be worked around with non-generic version of the interface. Also if OP wants compile time safety how much such collection would make sense?

Comment: Ah this looks like what I needed. Haven't played around with generics before, guess I have something else to investigate!
So I do have a list of these but it's of `IAction` (which `ICombinableAction` implements) so hopefully that should mean that this works fine.

Comment: I don't get what good the interface is if it has to refer to the base type.  This does not implement `ICombinableAction` as requested, it implements `ICombinableAction<MoveAllObjects>`.  Why have an interface at all?  Why not just have `MoveAllObjects.CombineActions(MoveAllObjects)`?  I don't understand what this accomplishes.  Can you give a usage example?  In particular can you demonstrate the parameter covariance required to name the covariant interface without naming the base class?

Comment: So I don't know if this is possible, my aim is to have a list of actions (objects which implement IAction). Some of these actions are combinable with themselves (e.g. MoveAllObjects actions can be combined) but not with other actiosn (MoveAllObjects cannot combine with MoveSingleObject). I need to be able to iterate over the list and combine all actions that are combinable. Checking if something is combinable would be done by checking if the Action implements ICombinableAction. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Malrig it seems that you need just to add check to interface `bool CombinableWith(ICombinableAction other)` and don't bother with generics.